# How to use subprocess.run with correct path on windows?

Tags: python, windows

On windows 10 using python 3.10.10 I am trying to run a windows executable, but there is some issue with the path to the folder of the executable. I am trying to run the following code

```
path =  r"C:/Program Files (x86)/STMicroelectronics/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/bin"
result = subprocess.run(command, cwd=path)
```

but I get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

(with and without the `r`).
I guess I have to "convert" the path somehow? But how exactly?

Also, the path DOES exist, and I am using similar path expressions (with the slash (`/`)) for other windows paths in the same python application running on windows.

Comment: I did use the path as-is using `os.chdir`. Worked fine. So why does the path work in `os.chdir` and suddenly not in `subprocess`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the warning [in the documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), windows cannot overwrite the current working directory unless you supply `shell=True`. Therefore, your method call would look like this:
`result = subprocess.run(command, cwd=path, shell=True)`

Comment: Ah interesting. But then I have to provide the command as one string and not as list as well? Correct?

Comment: The `command` (the variable) is a list of arguments, as you would use them, separated by spaces, in the comannd line. The additional keyword arguments (`cwd` and `shell`) are outside of what command you want to send. I unfortunately called it "command" in my answer, I'll fix that. The linked documentation supplies some examples at the very top how to use the method.

Comment: I now get an error `b"'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"`

Comment: How do you set `command`? Are you sure the path is the problem?

Comment: The path does not seem to be the problem anymore. But the command is not working, neither as list nor as string. I have `command="./STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=SWD mode=HOTPLUG -r8 0x08080000 8 -r8 0x08080C00 8 --halt"`

Comment: Should probably be `command=["STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe", "-c", "port=SWD", "mode=HOTPLUG", "-r8", "0x08080000", "8", "-r8", "0x08080C00", "8", "--halt"]`

Comment: No, here I also get the same error. Here is what I have used (copy and paste): `command=['./STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe', '-c', 'port=SWD', 'mode=HOTPLUG', '-r8', '0x08080000', '8', '-r8', '0x08080C00', '8', '--halt']`

Comment: Did you remove the `./` before the executable's name? I assume this is what the error `b"'.' is not recognized` is pointing at.

Comment: Ah thats it! Thats. Windows is sooo annoying!!